# push_back is more efficient than emplace_back?

Tags: c++, c++11, vector

I wanted to see the difference between push_back and emplace_back, as in several places I read recommendations as now it's better to use emplace_back as "it can do all push_back can do and more", so I expect it to be more efficient. But to my surprise

```cpp
#include <iostream>     
#include <vector>    

class A
{
public:
    A() { std::cout << "A const\n"; }
    ~A() { std::cout << "A dest\n"; }
    A(const A& a) { std::cout << "A copy const\n"; }
    A(A&& a) { std::cout << "A move const\n"; }
    A& operator=(const A& a) { std::cout << "A copy operator=\n"; return *this; }
    A& operator=(A&& a) { std::cout << "A move operator=\n";  return *this; }
};

int main () {
    std::vector<A> va;

    std::cout << "push:\n" << std::endl;
    va.push_back(A());

    std::cout << "\nemplace:\n";
    va.emplace_back(A());
    
    std::cout << "\nend:\n";

    return 0;
}
```

Output is

```
push:
A const
A move const
A dest

emplace:
A const
A move const
A copy const
A dest
A dest

end:
A dest
A dest
```

emplace_back calls the move constructor and then copies one when push_back calls only one move const. I checked with g++ (Ubuntu 7.4.0-1ubuntu1~16.04~ppa1) 7.4.0 and [online C++ shell](http://cpp.sh/).
Am I missing something?

Comment: Now do it in the other order, what happens? (Also don't use `const` as an abbreviation for constructor... ctor is better, since it doesn't conflict with, well, `const`).

Comment: When you insert the second element, the vector reallocates its storage (so it has to copy the first element to the new storage). Do `emplace_back` first and compare the results.

Comment: 1. move constructor not noexcept so vector invokes copy. 2. you reuse the same vector and cause a reallocation. 3. you call emplace_back with a temporary which defeats the purpose.

Comment: There's another variant you can try to round this experiment up, and it's `emplace_back()` - note the lack of arguments

Comment: Now, just invoke `va.emplace_back();`, without constructing a completely useless temporary object that is used to move-construct the value in the vector.

Comment: Thanks a lot everybody for the comments!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

**`push_back` is not more efficient, and the results you observe are due to the vector resizing itself.**

When you call `emplace` after `push_back`, the vector has to resize itself to make room for the second element. This means that it has to move the `A` that was originally inside the vector, making `emplace` appear more complex.

If you reserve enough space in the vector beforehand, this doesn't happen. Notice the call to `va.reserve(2)` after `va`'s creation:

```
#include <iostream>     
#include <vector>    

class A
{
    public:
    A() {std::cout << "A const" << std::endl;}
    ~A() {std::cout << "A dest" << std::endl;}
    A(const A& a) {std::cout << "A copy const" << std::endl;}
    A(A&& a) {std::cout << "A move const" << std::endl;}
    A& operator=(const A& a) {std::cout << "A copy operator=" << std::endl; return *this; }
    A& operator=(A&& a) {std::cout << "A move operator=" << std::endl;  return *this; }
};

int main () {
    std::vector<A> va;
    // Now there's enough room for two elements
    va.reserve(2);
    std::cout <<"push:" << std::endl;
    va.push_back(A());
    std::cout <<std::endl<< "emplace:" << std::endl;
    va.emplace_back(A());

    std::cout <<std::endl<< "end:" << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

The corresponding output is:

```
push:
A const
A move const
A dest

emplace:
A const
A move const
A dest

end:
A dest
A dest
```

**Can we make things even more efficient?** Yes! `emplace_back` takes whatever arguments you provide it, and forwards them to `A`'s constructor. Because `A` has a constructor that takes no arguments, you can also use `emplace_back` with no arguments! In other words, we change

```
va.emplace_back(A());
```

to

```
va.emplace_back(); // No arguments necessary since A is default-constructed
```

This results in no copy, and no move:

```
push:
A const
A move const
A dest

emplace:
A const

end:
A dest
A dest
```

**A note on vectors resizing:** It's important to note that the implementation of `std::vector` is smart. If `A` had been a trivially copyable type, `std::vector` might have been able resize in-place *without additional copying* using a system function similar to `realloc`. However because `A`s constructors and destruction contain code, `realloc` can't be used here.

Comment: You should also include the version with properly called emplace_back for comparison

Comment: Thanks a lot! So besides this aspect, when I pass object to emplace_back it's same as push_back, right?  A a, a1; va.emplace_back(a);  va.push_back(a1); both invokes copy constructor. Though I thought emplace_back  should make a move by default.

Comment: std::vector  allocates space for more than 2 elements when you insert the first element.  The pertformace hit is due to the way the OP uses emplace_back().  emplace_back() takes in the parameters to a constructor as parameters.  Calling emplace_back with a default constructed object as parameter calls the move constructor.  So, emplace_back(A{])  is 1 constructon, and 1 move.  Calling push_back(A{}) is 1 construction  and 1 copy.  Calling v.resize(v.size() + 1) is 1 in-place constructtion and is fastest.

For a simple class as in example, copy may be faster than move. which is a swap.

Comment: Both `push_back` and `emplace_back` move when provided with an object of type `A&&`. The thing with moving an object is that it doesn't prevent the destructor being called, because cleanup may still need to occur. There are proposals to allow programmers to indicate that objects are trivially movable to avoid superfluous destructor calls, but those haven't been accepted into the standard yet.

Comment: In a move, the objects are swapped and destructors are still being called.  In this example, the destrucftor is trivial.